# opening pgadmin4 with one click in ubuntu gnome

Tags: shell-script, gnome, python3

I wanted to run pgadmin4 (needs a browser to run) from a gnome menu icon. It then should open in firefox. 
The following works, when I open it twice. 
Entry in /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=pgAdmin IV
Comment=PostgreSQL Administration Tool
Exec=/home/xyz/pgadmin4.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=pgadmin3
Categories=Development;Database;
Keywords=PostgreSQL;SQL;
```

Content of /home/xyz/pgadmin4.sh:

```
python3 ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py; sleep 5; 
firefox -new-tab -url http://127.0.0.1:5050/browser/
```

I always have to start it twice. By introducing sleep I hoped it would delay the firefox process until pgAdmin4.py is up. Nonetheless it only will open after I open it twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
(python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py) & 
sleep 3; 
firefox -new-tab -url http://127.0.0.1:5050/browser/
```

This seems to have worked.